# How can I keep a symbol during gcc strip?

Tags: gcc, ld

Using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc, I'm working with a shared object that has an undefined reference to "main". I'm using dlopen() to open this library. However, when my program is compiled with "-Wl,-s", the symbol main is removed, which causes dlopen() to fail with an undefined symbol "main".

In gcc, is there any way I can perform a strip, but keep the symbol main?

Edit: even better, can I put just the symbol "main" in the dynamic section (similar to -rdynamic)?

Answer (score 0):

The shared object with an undefined reference to main appears to use the dynamic symbol table to search for the reference to "main". So, there are two options here:

1. Compile with "-Wl,-rdynamic". This will put all of the symbols into the dynamic symbol table. This works, but it results in a lot of extra symbols being put in there, too.
2. Compile with "-Wl,--dynamic-list=[path to my list file]". Then list "main" in the dynamic file to retain only main in the dynamic symbols table. This has the drawback that all dynamic references must now be managed, but for simple programs, this is adequate.

Example of (2):

Invocation:

```
 arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -fPIC mycode.c -Wl,-s,--dynamic-list=./dynamic_symbols.txt
```

dynamic_symbols.txt:

```
{ main; };
```